# what is the correct config for custom nuxt.js components directory?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, nuxt.js, dotenv

`<h1>Hello people</h1>`

I am learning to use nuxt.js and my question is about the use of custom directories different from the default structure of an application made with nuxt.js

`The issue: index.vue can't load .vue components from my components custom dir`

in the nuxt.config.file i have this conf:

```
  /*
  **Custom directory structure configuration paths
  **Change as desires
  **Important Note: This is a function not well documented on nuxt.org
  */

  dir: {
    views: 'views',
       components: 'views/components', 
       layouts: 'views/layouts',
       pages: 'views/pages',

    controllers: 'controllers/',
       middleware: 'controllers/middleware',

    models: 'models',
       data: 'models/data',
       files: 'models/files',
       store: 'models/store',

    sources: 'sources',
       assets: 'sources/assets',
       static: 'sources/static'
  },
```

and in the index.vue default file from nuxt create project comand have this at the end of file

```
<script>
import Logo from '~components/Logo.vue'
import VuetifyLogo from '~components/VuetifyLogo.vue'

export default {
  components: {
    Logo,
    VuetifyLogo
  }
}
</script>
```

as and extra data the content by default of the jsconfig.json file is

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "~/*": ["./*"],
      "@/*": ["./*"],
      "~~/*": ["./*"],
      "@@/*": ["./*"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", ".nuxt", "dist"]
}
```

The error message in the shell or comand prompt is

```
ERROR  Failed to compile with 2 errors                friendly-errors 12:12:09

These dependencies were not found:                    friendly-errors 12:12:09
                                                      friendly-errors 12:12:09
* ~/components/Logo.vue in 
  ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--2-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib
  ??vue-loader-options!./views/pages/index.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
* ~/components/VuetifyLogo.vue in 
  ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--2-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib
  ??vue-loader-options!./views/pages/index.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&

                                                      friendly-errors 12:12:09

To install them, you can run: npm install --save ~/components/Logo.vue ~/components/VuetifyLogo.vue
```

The error message at localhost/3000 is

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 
'~/components/Logo.vue' 
in '/home/user/desktop/nuxt/views/pages'

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 
'~/components/VuetifyLogo.vue' 
in '/home/user/desktop/nuxt/views/pages'
```

I do not know why is looking for a component on "views/pages/" if I already defined components at "views/components/" and "views" as "views", more info about what I do is explained at:

https://forum.vuejs.org/t/anyone-know-how-to-rename-move-a-nuxt-folder/44876/2

No errors when use the default dir structure.

!**Happy Holidays**

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the Nuxt documentation: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/component-discovery/

> If you have components in nested directories such as:
>
> | components/
>
> --| base/
>
> ----| foo/
>
> ------| Button.vue
>
> The component name will be based on its own path directory and
> filename. Therefore, the component will be:
>
> BaseFooButton